# How you apply IF statements to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that I am able to apply to a dataframe column, df['X'].

```
df['X'].str[:-2].str.zfill(2).apply('="{}"'.format).str.replace(' ', '')
```

Which returns ="08", Or ="03" within the column itself. However I only want to apply this condition if the column value is not equal to np.nan. Just wondered how you could apply such functions subject to an if statement?

```
df['X'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['X'].str.zfill(3).apply('="{}"'.format).str.replace(' ', '') if x['X'] != np.nan else x, 1).
```

I've tried this which I thought might work, but an error returns stating:

"AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')"

Comment: `if somevalue != np.nan: do something`

Comment: df['X'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['X'].str.zfill(3).apply('="{}"'.format).str.replace(' ', '') if x['X'] != np.nan else x, 1). I've tried this which I thought would work?